# YouTube API V3 Upload video throws exception

Tags: youtube-api

I am working with Web application with C# where user will browse a video file and web application will upload to YouTube via YouTube API V3. I am getting the error. Please advice where i am doing wrong?

Error: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: baseUri at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccess(Task task) at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) at Microsoft.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult() at Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUpload1.d__e.MoveNext() in c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\output\default\Src\GoogleApis\Apis[Media]\Upload\ResumableUpload.cs:line 459

I followed the below points.

1. Created ClientID for Webapplication and downloaded client_secrets.json file from API Access page.
2. Used the .Net sample code provided in https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#examples also referred same code from https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet
3. My application got authorized to YouTube API.
4. While uploading the video file, i am getting below error.

I am pasting below my code for your reference.

/* TestFileUploader.aspx */

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="TestFileUploader.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestFileUploader" Async="true" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="qaform" runat="server">
        <div>
            <p>
                <asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="FileUpload1" onchange="AddEventChoosePicture(this,'FileUpload1')"
                    Style="width: 100%;" />
            </p>
            <p>
                <asp:Button ID="submit" runat="server" OnClick="submit_Click" Text="Submit" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

/* TestFileUploader.aspx.cs */

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;
using QA.credential;

using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
using Google.Apis.Upload;

public partial class TestFileUploader : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                String FileUpload1_Ext = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(this.FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                UploadVideos(FileUpload1.FileContent, FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentType);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private async void UploadVideos(Stream uploadedStream, String contenttype)
    {
        try
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            String clientsecretkeypath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/client_secrets.json");
            using (var stream = new FileStream(clientsecretkeypath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user", System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);
            }

            // Create the service.
            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                //ApiKey = "AIzaSyAFxuAA4r4pf6VX75zEwCrIh5z4QkzOZ6M",
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = PhotoandVideoupload.applicationname
            });

            var video = new Video();
            video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
            video.Snippet.Title = "My Test Movie";
            video.Snippet.Description = "My description";
            video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "Autos" };
            video.Snippet.CategoryId = "2";
            video.Status = new VideoStatus();
            video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "unlisted";

            // Using snippet,status below throws 401(UnAuthorized issue).
            // Using snippet alone throws 404(Bad Request).
            //In both case, Null Exception throws for parameter baseURI.
            var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet", uploadedStream, contenttype);
            videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
            videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

            Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress = await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();

            switch (progress.Status)
            {
                case UploadStatus.Uploading:
                    Response.Write(String.Format("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent));
                    break;

                case UploadStatus.Failed:
                    Response.Write(String.Format("{0}<br/>", progress.Exception.Message));
                    Response.Write(String.Format("{0}<br/>", progress.Exception.StackTrace));
                    break;
            }


            // Also tried to read file from server path instead of uploading via fileupload control.
            /*
            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/1.mp4"), FileMode.Open))
            {
                var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", fileStream, contenttype);
                videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

                await videosInsertRequest.UploadAsync();
            }
            */

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.Message + " " + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
        }
    }

    void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(Google.Apis.Upload.IUploadProgress progress)
    {
        switch (progress.Status)
        {
            case UploadStatus.Uploading:
                Response.Write(String.Format("{0} bytes sent.", progress.BytesSent));
                break;

            case UploadStatus.Failed:
                Response.Write(String.Format("{0}<br/>", progress.Exception.Message));
                Response.Write(String.Format("{0}<br/>", progress.Exception.StackTrace));
                break;
        }
    }

    void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video video)
    {
        Response.Write(String.Format("Video id '{0}' was successfully uploaded.", video.Id));
    }

}
```

Please advice where i am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: You may want to use Fiddler to capture the underlying error. I experienced this error when I had one of the parameters wrong. With Fiddler logging the IP packets, I was able to see the underlying error that named the bad parameter. 

Google API DotNet Client [Issue 480](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=480) asks that the API be enhanced to return an object containing the underlying error. Please vote for it if you think it would help you do further debugging in the future.

Comment: Did you manage to get pass this Error?

Comment: @Briler: Not yet. if you found the actual problem please share here.

Comment: @DCI : I found out this is the generic Error, that ussualy comes after another exception. see on my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204080/big-query-exception-is-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-baseuri

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following change:

From:

```
var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet", uploadedStream, contenttype);
```

To:

```
var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video, "snippet,status", uploadedStream, contenttype);
```

Also, what is in contenttype? I use **video/*** as the contenttype for video uploads.

The status code 401 error may be because the YouTube API has not been authorized. Check that you have authorized the YouTube API for your credentials. Go to [Google Developers Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project) and click on your project name. Then click on "APIs" in the left navigation menu. Check to see that **YouTube Data API v3** is On.

Comment: When i changed as you suggested, i am getting "Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized)." and "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: baseUri".

Comment: I am reading content type from browsed file. I tried with .mp4 file. So, contenttype is passing as video/mp4 in this case.

I also tried to pass video/*, still same issue.

Comment: I revised my answer to address a possible reason for the status code 401 error.

Comment: After long back, I am trying to solve this issue. I tried all you tips. But not working.