# big query- Exception is Value cannot be null. Parameter name: baseUri

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery

I have been working with file uploads to BigQuery for some time now.

today I started getting:
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: baseUri

Seen this error on post on other Google services, but yet to have find an answer. any Idea?

I am using .net API - it seems like the error comes from Threading.dll - but I did not change anything on my code nor my account.

Comment: End up seeing that before this error, I got another error showing me that I was out quota for registered accounts. as it turns out, you always get this default error, no matter what caused it. in order to find out why- you will need to debug. anyway it is working for me once i opened an new service account

Comment: Response returns only one exception. How did you find out about the underlying error?