# C# Youtube api V3 - Value cannot be null error exception

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api

I am using C# Youtube Client API v3 to upload Captions to my video. Upload of video works fine (so I suppose no issue in authentication and credentials). I have tried various possible options recommended in similar questions but none of them worked for me.

My scope is as follows:

```
YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl, YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner
```

EDIT: (added below code related to service initialization as requested in one comment)

```
        UserCredential credential;
        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,

                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeForceSsl, YouTubeService.Scope.Youtubepartner},
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None
            );
        }

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
        });
```

And other important part of code is as follows:

```
        string zFile = @"subs.srt";

        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(zFile, FileMode.Open))
        {

            Caption cap = new Caption();
            cap.Snippet = new CaptionSnippet();
            cap.Snippet.VideoId = "_VIDEO_ID";
            cap.Snippet.Language = "en";
            cap.Snippet.Name = "Test";
            cap.Snippet.IsDraft = false;
            const int KB = 0x400;
            var minimumChunkSize = 256 * KB;


            CaptionsResource.InsertMediaUpload req = youtubeService.Captions.Insert(cap, "snippet" , fileStream, "*/*");
            req.Sync = true;
            req.ProgressChanged += videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
            req.ChunkSize = minimumChunkSize * 8;
            //req.ResponseReceived += videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;

            IUploadProgress result = req.Upload();
        }
```

Exception I get when I execute above code as is follows:

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: baseUri
```

Please note that I have already tried with `snippet, status` also but didn't help.

Appreciate support from the community.

Comment: where do you intialize youtubeService?
can you give code of that ?

Comment: Just added code related to youtubeService initialization in the Edit part.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check

```
CaptionsResource.InsertMediaUpload req = youtubeService.Captions.Insert(cap, "snippet" , fileStream, "*/*");
```

Look at this thread: [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25763038/youtube-api-v3-upload-video-throws-exception)

Comment: Actually I had a look at that thread previously and even in that thread he ended up with same error which I have and it didn't help. Also I mentioned that I had tried both "snippet" and "snippet, status" but I get same error in both cases.